# How to make radio button cause an event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the `innerHTML` of an element or even just alert something when the user clicks on a radio.

This is my JavaScript:

```
function ways() {
    var set = document.getElementsByName("lala");

    if(lala[0].checked) {
        alert("this is so cool it's finally working");
    }
    else if(lala[1].checked) {
        alert("Alhamdulillah it's all going great");
    }
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="lala" value="human" onclick="ways()">
<input type="radio" name="lala" value="robot" onclick="ways()">
```

Comment: It always helps to say what is your current output.

Answer (score 1):

You place the result of `document.getElementsByName("lala")` in a variable called `set`. You never defined a variable called `lala`, so in order to access these elements you must access `set`.

Everything else about your code was correct.

```js
function ways() {

  var set = document.getElementsByName("lala");

  if (set[0].checked) {
    alert("this is so cool it's finally working");
  } else if (set[1].checked) {
    alert("Alhamdulillah it's all going great");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="lala" value="human" onclick="ways()">
<input type="radio" name="lala" value="robot" onclick="ways()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using variable `set` in the condition which is holding the radio buttons:

```js
function ways() {
  var set = document.getElementsByName("lala");
  if(set[0].checked) {
    alert("this is so cool it's finally working");
  }
  else if(set[1].checked) {
    alert("Alhamdulillah it's all going great");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="lala" value="human" onclick="ways()">
<input type="radio" name="lala" value="robot" onclick="ways()">
```

Answer (score 0):

the js engine could not find a variable as `lala`. Probably you are getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: lala is not defined` in the console.

use the below code

```
function ways() {

  if(document.getElementsByName("lala")[0].checked) {
    alert("this is so cool it's finally working");
  }
  else if(document.getElementsByName("lala")[1].checked) {
    alert("Alhamdulillah it's all going great");
  }
}
```